# Cleanup of resources with Hive Session Close

Tags: hadoop, hive, emr, hue

I need to create some resources(Geocoder with Binary Data)'s object in my custom UDF. These resources should be created one time for a UDF, and each mapper will hold single instance of this resource So I am using a singleton factory that creates this resource and hold its static reference.

To dispose these resources I am using a shutdown hook, and it is working fine with Hive CLI console (Putty), if I exit from the console than it dispose all the resources.

But I am not able to dispose these resources with Hue UI, even if i close the hive session, still these resources exists.

Can someone pls help me to find a cleaner approach to dispose these resources with Hue UI.

As a workaround I created a new UDF to dispose these resources - `SELECT DisposeGeocoders();`. But it is a overhead for user.

Answer (score 0):

what are these values in [hue.init](https://github.com/cloudera/hue/blob/master/desktop/conf.dist/hue.ini) file in your environment? (default these are true, but I would check these properties:

```
# Use session-length cookies. Logs out the user when she closes the browser window.
expire_at_browser_close=true

# Hue will try to close the Hive query when the user leaves the editor page.
#This will free all the query resources in HiveServer2, but also make its results inaccessible.
close_queries=true

# Use session-length cookies. Logs out the user when she closes the browser window.
expire_at_browser_close=true
```

Comment: #Ronak Patel - Both of these parameters are set as "true".

Comment: And restart the hue(if it was not after setting these)...see if  your problem resolves

Comment: Yes I restarted it :)